# Multiple request using utl_http without waiting for response Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

In the below sample code can I make multiple requests (h_req) without waiting for the response. Basically want to send many different payloads at once.
I read online,to use DBMS_JOB to call the procedure multiple times.

Will it give too many request open error? Or is there something in UTL_HTTP for multi request.

```
 BEGIN
              h_req:= UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST(
                                      url => 'https://myorg.org/api/ios',
                                      METHOD => 'POST',
                                      http_version => 'HTTP/1.1'
                                    );
              UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(h_req,'Content-Type','application/json');
              UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(h_req,'Content-Length',vlen);
              
              WHILE v_offset <= vlen
                  LOOP
                    UTL_HTTP.WRITE_TEXT(v_request,SUBSTR(vbody,v_offset,32767));
                    v_offset := v_offset + 32767;
                  END LOOP;
         
              h_resp:= UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(h_req);
              UTL_HTTP.READ_TEXT(h_resp,v_text,4000);
              UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(h_resp);
        
        END;
```

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you can set the limit in Oracle parameters. Have a look at documentation.